# Proper way to use MySQL fulltext search on a keyword string?

Tags: joomla-3.x, mysql, search

I have a keyword string on which I want to do full text searching.

The current search query in the model is as follows:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $keyword = $jinput->get('keyword', '', 'NULL');
    if($keyword!=''){
         $keyword = $db->Quote('%' . $db->escape($keyword, true) . '%');
            $query->where('( a.title LIKE '.$keyword.'  OR  a.features LIKE '.$keyword.'  OR  a.brand LIKE '.$keyword.' )');
    }
```

However this returns very poor search results. For example, the search string `Google Nexus 5` matches, whereas `Google 5 Nexus` does not. What is the correct way to convert this query to fulltext searching in Joomla 3.3

Comment: Do you want results that only have all 3 words?

Answer (score 1):

*NB. this isn't tested code just typed into the browser so caveat emptor*

The first step would be to check the search term for spaces and then `explode()` it it into an `array()` that contains each of the space delimited strings. e.g.

```
$keywordArray = explode(" ", $keyword);
```

If you want to *only* find content that has **all keywords** in it, then you also need to use an `AND` rather than an `OR`. By the way, the `$db->quote()` call you have automatically performs an `escape()` the way you're using it (I'm not sure if it detects the previously escaped text with the extra escaping or not in your case).

So, to build your `where`'s you could loop through the array with something like:

```
if($keyword!=''){
    $keywordArray = explode(" ", $keyword);

    foreach ($keywordArray as $keyword)
    {
        $searchTerm = $db->Quote('%' . $keyword . '%');
        $query->where('( a.title LIKE '.$searchTerm.' AND a.title LIKE '.$searchTerm.' AND a.title LIKE '.$searchTerm.' )');
        $query->where('( a.features LIKE '.$searchTerm.' AND a.features LIKE '.$searchTerm.' AND a.features LIKE '.$searchTerm.' )');
        $query->where('( a.brand LIKE '.$searchTerm.' AND a.brand LIKE '.$searchTerm.' AND a.brand LIKE '.$searchTerm.' )');
    }
}
```

Having said that, this could be some serious load on MySQL, it's a relational database after all not a search engine. You may want to do things like:

1. Give the user the option to search in just one of those columns
2. Limit the number of words on input, imagine a search with 10 or more words in it.
3. Look at options like `MATCH` and `MATCH AGAINST`

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same issue especially when you have large data sets. I tried also the MATCH and MATCH AGAINST solutions but they were not really helpful for full text search. At the end I wrote my own [finder plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Smart_Search_plug-in) and do migrate my extensions for full text search to use [smart search](http://docs.joomla.org/Smart_Search_quickstart_guide). Don't know if this is an option for you.